# MATLAB: how to read every Nth line of a text file?

Tags: matlab, text, file-io, textscan

I have some data that's formatted as follows:

```
dtau     E_av        variance    N_sims      Time
0.001   0.497951    0.000211625 25      Sun Apr  3 18:18:12 2011

dtau     E_av        variance    N_sims      Time
0.002   0.506784    0.000173414 25      Sun Apr  3 18:18:58 2011
```

Now I want to read the first 4 columns (anything but the time) of every third line into MATLAB using textscan; after using `fid = fopen('data.text')`, I basically have to loop this:

```
results = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f', 1,'headerlines',1);
```

Any ideas?
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fid = fopen('data.text')
while ~feof(fid)
  results = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f', 1,'headerlines',1);
  //Processing...

  for i = 1:2
    fgets(fid)
  end
end
```

`fgets` reads until the end of a line, and returns the text on that line. So, just call it twice to skip two lines (discarding the return value of the function).

Comment: Your implementation may still break, depending on the number of lines in the file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you know you will have 5 column labels (i.e. strings) followed by 4 numeric values followed by 5 strings (e.g. `'Sun'`, `'Apr'`,  `'3'`, `'18:18:12'`, and `'2011'`), you can actually read all of your numeric data into a single N-by-4 matrix with one call to [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html):

```
fid = fopen('data.text','r');                    %# Open the file
results = textscan(fid,[repmat(' %*s',1,5) ...   %# Read 5 strings, ignoring them
                        '%f %f %f %f' ...        %# Read 4 numeric values
                        repmat(' %*s',1,5)],...  %# Read 5 strings, ignoring them
                   'Whitespace',' \b\t\n\r',...  %# Add \n and \r as whitespace
                   'CollectOutput',true);        %# Collect numeric values
fclose(fid);                                     %# Close the file
results = results{1};                            %# Remove contents of cell array
```